@react-three/fiber create a sphere with diameter equals to the width of the canvas
I am new to the library and I would like to do something that i think is simple to have a sphere of diameter the same as the canvas.
I thought what I was doing was simple, but I was mistaken, I tried reading the documentation for answers but I have not found much, I tried AIs but to no avail...
I tried to calculare the readius based on the z distance but the diameter of the sphere is not the width...
Can someone help ??
This is the code
import { useRef, useEffect, useState, useCallback } from "react";
import { Canvas, useThree } from "@react-three/fiber";
import * as THREE from "three";

function ResizableSphere() {
    const sphereRef = useRef<THREE.Mesh>(null);
    const { size, camera } = useThree();
    const [radius, setRadius] = useState(1);
    const { getCurrentViewport } = useThree((state) => state.viewport);
    const { width, height, factor } = getCurrentViewport(camera, [0, 0, 1]);
    const resizeHandler = useCallback(() => {
        if (sphereRef.current) {
            console.log(width, height, factor);
            const canvasWidth = width * factor;
            const aspect = width / height;

            const distance = camera.position.z / 2;
            console.log("distance", distance);
            const vFOV = THREE.MathUtils.degToRad(
                (camera as THREE.PerspectiveCamera).fov
            );
            console.log(distance, vFOV, aspect);
            const height_ = 2 * Math.tan(vFOV / 2) * distance;
            const width_ = height_ * aspect;
            const newRadius = width_ / 2;

            console.log(
                `Canvas Width: ${canvasWidth}, Calculated Width: ${width}, New Radius: ${newRadius}`
            );
            setRadius(newRadius);
        }
    }, [size, camera, width, height, factor]);

    useEffect(() => {
        resizeHandler();

        window.addEventListener("resize", resizeHandler);
        return () => {
            window.removeEventListener("resize", resizeHandler);
        };
    }, [resizeHandler]);

    useEffect(() => {
        if (sphereRef.current) {
            const newGeometry = new THREE.SphereGeometry(radius, 32, 32);
            if (sphereRef.current.geometry)
                sphereRef.current.geometry.dispose();
            sphereRef.current.geometry = newGeometry;
        }
    }, [radius]);

    return (
        <mesh ref={sphereRef} scale={[1, 1, 1]}>
            <meshStandardMaterial color="orange" />
        </mesh>
    );
}

function MyCanvas() {
    return (
        <Canvas camera={{ position: [0, 0, 10] }}>
            <ambientLight intensity={0.5} />
            <pointLight position={[0, 0, 10]} />
            <ResizableSphere />
        </Canvas>
    );
}

export default MyCanvas;

